# Allow user to download file and then redirect to other page

Tags: python-3.x, django, file, download

I have a function like:

```
def download(requests):
    with open(file_path2, 'rb') as fh:
         response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path2)
         return response    #it stop executing here as we return.
    os.remove(file_path2) 
    return render(request, 'user/charts.html', {'res': 'The file has decrypted'})
```

So what the function needs to do is, start the file downloading and after download delete the file from system then redirect to other page.

But the problem is,for implementing downloading functionality , I use `return` and then it stops, So how can I execute next statements ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return` you can print the file and write `continue`.

What I would suggest to do is allow the file to be downloadable by adding the `download` attribute to the HTML tag:

```html
<a href="image.jpg" download>
```

Now for redirecting, you can write a function that is called once this button is clicked to `redirect` the user to another page.